# Do I have to verify a JWT token per request?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, firebase-admin

We've got an API, and we've got a couple client applications (app, webapp, etc.).

We're using Firebase Auth (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens); I'm easily verifying the integrity of the JWT tokens generated on my Client SDKs, however, I'm facing a minor issue.

Per request, we pass an authentication token / jwt token along in the HTTP Headers in order to make sure every call is authenticated. This generates significant overhead, since each tokens integrity check takes up about 200-400 ms, on average.

I was thinking of storing the keys in memory or something with the (`exp`) expiration time, but I'm not really sure if this would be a great solution. I would just verify the key with a big list of keys given out, which clears when the keys expiration date clears.

How should I approach this? Is there no way around the time overhead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the time really spent in verifying the token? You might want to see if you can see exactly where it goes, because decoding the token should be quite fast. But if you're retrieving the public key for the account every time, that could explain part of it of course.

Aside from that, there's nothing wrong with caching the `exp` or any other decoded information for a token, as long as that token is not expired. It's in fact a fairly standard space-vs-time trade-off. Just keep in mind that you'll be using memory for each token there, so this will add up as you get more concurrent users.

Comment: We decode the token with the Python Admin SDK. We generate a dict based on the JSON data in the JWT token, and return that with a JSON response. I'll check whether we're doing anything time-consuming or cpu-intensive, along with just verifying the token.

Comment: I was checking with check_revoked=True. With check_revoked=False, it takes about 60-90ms.

Comment: Aha, checking it its revoked is for sure gonna take a while, since it needs to actively check with the server. It's best to treat the JWTs as bearer tokens, and assume that if they're not expired, they're valid. That's what all (most?) Google services do as far as I know.

Comment: I see, the way they're implemented they should always be valid, so treating them as Bearer tokens probably is going to be the way to go. I don't really like the 60-90ms time it take to verify the integrity of a JWT token. Probably nothing I can do, computational complexity & Python bottleneck I guess.

Comment: To add; I can get it down to about 15-20ms; I'm developing localhost so if my CPU & RAM is busy, response time goes up. Should not be 60-90ms in production.

Comment: If you implement the cache you mentioned, you'd only have to decode a token when you first get it. After that you can just compare the incoming token against the cache (which is likely a lot faster), using the token itself as the key.